# AWS SDK JS S3 getObject Stream Metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have code similar to the following to pipe an S3 object back to the client as the response using Express, which is working perfectly.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {
    Bucket: 'myBucket',
    Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'
};
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

Problem is, I want to be able to access some of the properties in the response I get back from S3, such as `LastModified`, `ContentLength`, `ETag`, and more. I want to use those properties to send as headers in the response to the client, as well as for logging information.

Due to the fact that it is creating a stream I can't figure out how to get those properties.

I have thought about doing a separate `s3.headObject` call to get the data I need, but that seems really wasteful, and will end up adding a large amount of cost at scale.

I have also considered ditching the entire stream idea and just having it return a buffer, but again, that seems really wasteful to be using extra memory when I don't need it, and will probably add more cost at scale due to the extra servers needed to handle requests and the extra memory needed to process each request.

---

How can I get back a stream using `s3.getObject` along with all the metadata and other properties that `s3.getObject` normally gives you back?

---

Something like the following would be amazing:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {
    Bucket: 'myBucket',
    Key: 'myImageFile.jpg',
    ReturnType: 'stream'
};
const s3Response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
s3Response.Body.pipe(res); // where `s3Response.Body` is a stream
res.set("ETag", s3Response.ETag);
res.set("Content-Type", s3Response.ContentType);
console.log("Metadata: ", s3Response.Metadata);
```

But according to the S3 documentation it doesn't look like that is possible. Is there another way to achieve something like that?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the original [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html)?  `var req = s3.getObject(params);` then `req.createReadStream().pipe(res)`;  ... and you have `req` which should offer some useful properties or perhaps an event you can listen for.  I haven't tried it but there's a lot of useful-looking stuff hiding in there.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah that doesn't really work. Because that data I need is only available on the `end` event. And by that point the headers have already been sent, so I can't adjust the headers at that point.

Comment: Oh, I wondered where `res` was defined.  I see what you're doing, now.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah, I'm using Express as a web server, and just piping the data from S3 through as the response to the client.

Comment: There's the `httpHeaders` event where you can get the headers when they finish arriving, and `httpData` where it looks like you should see the response body data arriving in chunks, which you could stream to the pipe yourself.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920284/getting-s3-object-metadata-then-creating-stream/49075095. See my answer.

Comment: @cementblocks That is semi helpful, but I still am not sure it completely works. When I pass in a `IfNoneMatch` that matches AWS-SDK throws an error `NotModified: null`. Even if I try to catch it with `request.on("error"` it still crashes my server. For some reason if it returns a 404, I'm able to catch it on the stream object and it successfully catches the error without crashing.

Comment: @cementblocks This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43438576/894067) fixed that problem. I don't think there is a way to move my bounty to another question sadly. If you answer tho, at the end of the bounty period if there are no better answers I will give you the bounty if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've found and tested the following. it works.

as per: [Getting s3 object metadata then creating stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920284/getting-s3-object-metadata-then-creating-stream?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
function downloadfile (key,res) {

  let stream;

  const params = { Bucket: 'xxxxxx', Key: key }
  const request = s3.getObject(params);


    request.on('httpHeaders', (statusCode, httpHeaders) => {
        console.log(httpHeaders);
        stream.pipe(res)
        stream.on('end', () => { 
            console.log('were done')
        })
    })
    stream = request.createReadStream()
```

}

Comment: Aren't you defeating the purpose of streaming if you're fetching the object ahead of time, as well?